# Not able to extract value from XML node using parse_xml() in KQL

Tags: xml, azure, kql, azure-log-analytics

Here is my KQL but it is not giving expected results and returning NULL. My objective is to extract the value from the XML node.

```
print input_xml = "<tns7:errorCode>MESSAGE_ERR_9999</tns7:errorCode>"
| extend d=tostring(parse_xml(input_xml))
| project d
```

Comment: This appears to be related to the xml node name including a colon (`:`). As a workaround, if you can eliminate that (e.g. replace with an underscore, `_`), that should work

Comment: @YoniL. Thanks. It helps but as I am reading application logs, I was looking for a way where I can read directly the Message code without doing a replace operation.

Comment: The XML is invalid. `tns7` is a namespace and the XML lacks the declaration of that namespace. See example https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Comment: I wonder how you progresses with this

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I did something like this                                                                | extend LogEntry_r=replace_string(LogEntry, ':', '_')
| extend LogEntry_j=parse_xml(LogEntry_r)
| project LogEntry_j.tns7_errorCode
| summarize count() by tostring(LogEntry_j_tns7_errorCode)

Comment: Theoretical you could have collisions between different namespaces (same field name in that appear in more than one namespace). The ideal path would have been to fix it in the source